# Google Cloud Storage: what is the difference between WRITER and OWNER?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

This seems like a simple question, but I have not been able to find the answer online.  What specific actions can the OWNER of a bucket do that a WRITER of that bucket (or any object) cannot do?  The reason I ask is that I noticed that one of my "logs" buckets has cloud-logs@google.com as an OWNER and I'm wondering if I can (and possibly should?) change this to WRITER -- is it the OWNER because it actually created the bucket for me?  if an Google app creates a bucket for me, would it be a good idea for it to them remove itself as an OWNER after making "project-owners" the OWNER?  Also, wouldn't it make more sense for the "role" of project-editors to be WRITER rather than OWNER so that there is a difference between a project "owner" and a project "editor"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complete details on the different permissions, there's a complete chart of the differences between Reader, writer, and owner for buckets and objects [in the GCS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#permissions).

A reader of a bucket can list its contents. A writer of a bucket can also delete objects and insert new ones. An owner of a bucket can also edit bucket metadata and ACLs.

According to the [Cloud Logging Docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export#manual-access), OWNER is the correct permission for cloud-logs@google.com.